# How would I go about having placeholder divs that are then "overwritten" later with PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

Some clarification:

I want to have 6 placeholder divs for strikes, so to speak, in a game.

So like `[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]`.

Which will be white squares with a black border.

After they make a bad guess, I want the first div to be overwritten with a red box holding the guess. Basically the above, but fully red and a number in the middle. ex: `[9]`

How would I go about doing this with PHP/CSS/HTML? I'm totally used to echo statements, so I was thinking about echoing each one out. But if I had divs there to begin with, it would just go after them, not overwrite.

I was thinking something along the lines of background images, at least in concept (not actual images) where the new guesses just go overtop the old ones. Would that be the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP completes all data at DOM complete.   To update the DOM in real time, you can either use Ajax or your own JS block, node.js, etc.

Comment: I know, but I'm thinking of positioning it overtop, which is what PHP can do, and I'm curious if that's the best solution.

Comment: You can render the divs and then use absolute positioning _in the same request_ to render things on top. But I think Jrey is right: you actually need to render changes well after the page is served, in which case you'll need JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

While you have tagged for CSS and PHP, you would be better off using jQuery.

CSS stacks would simply get confusing and messy fast, and PHP renders on load, unless you use AJAX so again can get messy fast.

For the example of above  you could use:

```
function badguess() {
    $('#box2').css("color","red");
 }
```

If you wanted to add text to the box you could also use:

```
  function badguess(){
    $('#box2').css("color","red");            
    $('#box2').append('<p>WRONG</p>');
  }
```

Links:

.Append() - http://api.jquery.com/append/

.CSS() -  http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @halfer
Thanks for the cleanup :3